# Flags flying Souls

Tags: grammar, writing, poetic

If I may hold your attention for the moment while I decode the seemingly cryptic title, I shall endeavour to make the question worth your while.

I would like to know if I can use, both in speech and writing, the concept that "national flags *fly* souls".

I read this once, as a comment on the British Empire:

> *At the empire's height her flag **flew** more than five hundred million souls and over a quarter of the world.*

Jingoistic connotations aside, (literally) a flag, the way I see it, cannot fly souls.

However, I do think it does hold some poetic merit, so was looking to ask if I can justify writing in this fashion.

Thank you.

Comment: Ah, all right then. Was thinking of that anyway. Thanks for the time.

Comment: It's pretty extreme 'poetic licence' at the arithmetic as well as the linguistic level - [*By 1922 the British Empire held sway over about **458 million** people*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_British_Empire#.22First.22_British_Empire_.281583.E2.80.931783.29). Which is undeniably "more than five million", but that's an unusual way of putting it.

Comment: Ah. I originally put five hundred million. Will correct. Thanks for spotting the mistake.

Comment: @Josh61: Each to their own, I guess. I think talking about "flags flying souls" is just *poetry manque*. So just our comments here should be enough to suggest this is either "writing advice" or a matter of opiion. But I think it's mainly "OP isn't familiar with standard English".

Comment: Could it be that it is missing an 'over' after flew?

Comment: As the sentence stands the verb *flew* is called upon to act in both transitive and intransitive senses, which is intolerable to even the most libertine poet. I don't think this is a rhetorical flourish at all; I think that *over* has been inadvertently dropped before *five*.

Comment: Maybe it's me... but that statement would trip me up.  I'd prefer "...flag flew ***over*** five hundred million souls," or, maybe, "...flag ***enfolded*** five hundred million souls".

Comment: @SamuelVimes You crossed the finish line first: post it and claim your upvotes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I resent that! :D On a more serious note thanks everyone. Again, I only read this once and have been pondering it ever since. StackExchange seemed to be about a good place as any to ask about it.

Comment: @Oldbag, thank you very much, but it is ok if you want to post it yourself, we were only a couple of seconds apart anyway =)

Comment: Alex, I am voting to close this question because you **pointlessly attempted to use flowery language** in asking your question. I'd appreciate it is you **never do that**.  Write like Churchill (short direct sentences), or do not write at all.  Your first and penultimate sentences should be deleted.

Comment: Sure, excuse me.

Comment: @Alex: Seriously, ELU doesn't do "writing advice". If we ignore my "isn't familiar with standard English" (not the most tactful comment I've ever made on ELU, I'll readily admit! :) I think the best home for this question would be [writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/), because it is essentially "writing advice".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is almost certainly assuming that a typo isn't a typo.

Comment: Sure, I'd vote too if I could figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a **simple mistake**, it should be simply:

> At the empire's height her flag flew **over** more than five hundred million souls and over a quarter of the world.

There is absolutely nothing more to it that that.

It is that simple.

There is utterly nothing else to see or discuss here.

**It's a typo**, and/or just poor writing.

I'm afraid I feel Josh is wrong, it simply **is not** poetic license.

(1) it makes no sense, zero, as poetic license. it would be a Dada-esque "collection of words" if anything

(2) it is terribly obvious that one word is missing.

(3) Note carefully that **even if** you construe the clause as a weird form, it simply **does not match grammatically** with the following clause.  QED it's just a typo.